# Can I use "USING SCAN ..." and "USING INDEX ..." in the same cypher query in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was reading about optimizing queries and came across a post which said that sometimes cypher executor might miss using the index or might not scan all the labels instead of the provided one, so its best to explicitly state which index to use and which label to scan. (That's my understanding)

So when i tried to do so, it gave me this error

```
Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: Failed to fulfil the hints of the query.
Could not solve these hints: 'USING SCAN (some node)'
```

I have a query like this:

```
MATCH (n:Label1)-[r:SOME_REL]->(n2:LABEL3)
```

Where `n2` can have `:Label2` and `:Label3`.

I am not able to run these queries:

```
MATCH (n:Label1{property:val})-[r:SOME_REL]->(n2:LABEL3)
  USING INDEX n:Label1(property)
  USING SCAN n2:Label3
RETURN n

MATCH (n:Label1{property:val})-[r:SOME_REL]->(n2:LABEL3)
  USING SCAN n2:Label3
  USING INDEX n:Label1(property)
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 2):

A `MATCH` pattern can only use an index (e.g., `:Label1(property)`) if it specifies both a label AND a property value. So, for instance, this would work:

```
MATCH (n:Label1 {property: 123})-[r:SOME_REL]->(n2:Label3)
USING INDEX n:Label1(property)
USING SCAN n2:Label3
RETURN n;
```

*Note: This query also uses a consistent capitalization for `Label3`.*